# Objective-C Runtime

Tags: objective-c, runtime

[The Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) says:

> “Deprecated” below means “deprecated in Mac OS X version 10.5 for 32-bit code, and disallowed for 64-bit code.”

and I would like to use **class_setSuperclass** in Max OS X version 10.5 even though I still can do it the compiler gives warning telling me its deprecated but it still builds and the Bundle is still usable.

My question is what would be the equivalent in Max OS X 10.5?

Comment: jajaja At least is is documented:  *" **Special Considerations** You should not use this function"*

Comment: For what purpose do you want to use `class_setSuperclass`? Depending on that, people can suggest other solutions without using `class_setSuperclass`.

Comment: My reason for using class_setSuperclass is to write a patch to fix some problems in Microsoft Entourage under 10.5 not displaying HTML the way Apple Mail does and by patch I mean a SIMBL plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a guess using it is probably not a good idea.  I know with the shift towards 64 bit several things in the runtime changed and didn't have a replacement.

The docs even explicitly say not to touch, and doesn't give exception to that.

You can however use `class_addMethod` to add functionality to a given preexisting class.  However, that is also doable via categories.

You can use `class_replaceMethod` to override a method as well, another possible method is to use a category (or `class_addMethod`) to add a replacement method.  Then using `method_exchangeImplementations` you can swap them so as to have the original still available for calling.

In general though most of this is kinda dark voodoo, and unless you're comfortable with and willing to test a lot, I'd look for an alternative design.

Comment: Instead of using class_setSuperclass and swizzle methods around I will  use class_addMethod then swizzle.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a direct equivalent.

I know every time I've played with the class hierarchy at runtime I've been burned. You should be able to achieve the same results, albeit more verbosely via delegation, and I'd imagine that's what they want.